# Any way to create an aura:if component dynamically?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, dynamic

Is it possible to create an `aura:if` component having a `isTrue` evaluating dynamically to the value of an attribute?

I've tried the following and I'm getting a checkbox that is visible regardless of the value of the `visible` attribute.

```xml
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="visible" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}"/>

    <form>
        {!v.body}
    </form>
</aura:component>
```

```js
({
    onInit: function (component) {
        $A.createComponents([
                ["aura:if",{
                    "isTrue" : component.getReference("v.visible")
                }],
                ["lightning:input",{
                    "type" : "checkbox",
                    "label": "Some Label"
                }]
            ],
            function(components, status, errorMessage) {
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    var body = component.get("v.body");
                    var auraIf = components[0];
                    var checkbox = components[1];
                    auraIf.set("v.body", checkbox);
                    body.push(auraIf);
                    component.set("v.body", body);
                } else if (status === "ERROR") {
                    console.log("Error", errorMessage);
                }
            });
})
```

Comment: A reference to an attribute value works fine for example when used for the `value` attribute in `lightning:input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve my goal by creating a custom component containing an `aura:if` inside, that looks exactly like this:

```xml
<!--c:CustomComponent-->
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="isTrue" type="Boolean" required="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="else" type="Aura.Component[]"/>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isTrue}">
        {!v.body}
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            {!v.else}
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

and creating the component dynamically exactly the same way I've tried before but with the custom component

```js
({
    onInit: function (component) {
        $A.createComponents([
                ["c:CustomComponent",{
                    "isTrue" : component.getReference("v.visible")
                }],
                ["lightning:input",{
                    "type" : "checkbox",
                    "label": "Some Label"
                }]
            ],
            function(components, status, errorMessage) {
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    var body = component.get("v.body");
                    var auraIf = components[0];
                    var checkbox = components[1];
                    auraIf.set("v.body", checkbox);
                    body.push(auraIf);
                    component.set("v.body", body);
                } else if (status === "ERROR") {
                    console.log("Error", errorMessage);
                }
            });
})
```

Now, the `isTrue` attribute is bound to the reference of the `value` attribute and it's dynamically reflected when the attribute value is changed, opposite to what happened in case of an `aura:if`.

Answer (score 3):

No. Most of the Aura library cannot be created dynamically, as they have special rules about how their contents are rendered. This includes `aura:if`, `aura:iteration`, and `aura:renderIf`. Internally, those components accept an array of Aura.ComponentRef instead of the usual Aura.Component elements.

This type of object is a "raw" component (one that has *not yet* been created), while Aura.Component represents a "cooked" component (one that *has* been created already). There's no way to get at "raw" components that I've seen, as `$A.createComponents` returns only "cooked" components, and those can't be used as templates.

I've posted this answer as it was a bit long for a comment, but this is certainly an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You'll need to come up with a different solution to your problem, which will involve asking about your original "X" instead of this "Y" question.